# Why am I getting a DDE error when opening a file in Explorer that associated with our application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-explorer, dde

Our legacy `MDI` desktop application uses the `/dde` switch in the association.  When opening a file associated with it, **and the application has not yet started up,** Explorer pops up the following error:

```
There was a problem sending the command to the program.
```

The registry looks something like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document]
@="App File"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\DefaultIcon]
@="d:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyApp\\version\\app.exe,1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\App\\app.exe\" /dde"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\open\ddeexec]
@="[open(\"%1\")]"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\print]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\print\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\App\\app.exe /dde"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\print\ddeexec]
@="[print(\"%1\")]"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\printto]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\printto\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\App\\app.exe /dde"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\App.Document\shell\printto\ddeexec]
@="[printto(\"%1\",\"%2\",\"%3\",\"%4\")]"
```

Just to be clear, I just took these entries from the registry.  I'm not well versed in what they do, but I can hazard a guess that they link the verbs to actions by way of the [DDE interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**Note that if the application has already started up, the document opens up fine in that instance.  This is only an issue if the application hasn't started up and must execute a new instance of the application.**

So, what is happening is that the associated file is opened through Explorer by double clicking on it, and the associated application is executed.  Explorer would then pop up that message and our application would do nothing.  Double clicking on the file a second time would then open the document.

We've had this issue previously, but we just decided to ignore it for a few years as no one really knew what it was and we had other priorities at the time.  Our workaround was to tell the user to change the `/dde` to `"%1"`.  Yeah, lame, but it worked well enough.  One issue with doing that though, was that it would execute a new instance of the application, regardless if the application was already running or not.

Anyways, this issue is now starting to become an actual problem and needs to be fixed.  One of our developers is saying that the DDE system is antiquated and we should try writing a COM component that will redirect to our application like Visual Studio does as debugging this issue could take a while.  I've not verified that yet, nor researched how much effort that would be.  However, either may be resource intensive, either on the debugging or the research side, so I'm trying to do some preliminary research to see what I can dig up and determine which is the better approach.

Stepping in the code, I was able to determine that it gets to a `::SetWindowPlacement()` call and stepping over that will cause the error message box to pop up (if Explorer hasn't timed out first).  As it is a WINAPI, I cannot step into that function to see what it is doing.

The application is written mostly in VC/VC++ using MFC/API and other libraries.

So my question is, does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

## Edit

Some additional information:

I was able to intercept all of the `SendMessage()`/`PostMessage()`/`DispatchMessage()` function calls non-destructively, which will log all of the messages.  This was achieved by using MS Detours 3.0.

What I am seeing is that there are 4 `SendMessage` calls with a `WM_COPYDATA` message which appears to be coming out of `shell32.dll`.  However, it doesn't appear to be the messages that are at fault though.

Putting a `__debugbreak()` when it detects the `WM_COPYDATA` message results in no error until a few steps beyond.  How far depends on if I step or if I put a breakpoint and run the code to somewhere beyond where I thought I was getting the error.  Using `DebugBreak()` seems to slow down the debugger to the point where I can't step without the error showing up.

What I can't understand is that there doesn't appear to be any rhyme or reason as to what is triggering the error message to pop up.  I doesn't appear to be a timeout as the timeout appears to be long until I start stepping in the code, and sometimes no messages are being Sent/Posted by the code.  So there's no `WM_DDE_ACK` (or any message for that matter) being sent back to the Explorer window that has initiated this.  This is very frustrating.

To further complicate things, if I use the intrinsic `__debugbreak()` call and I have a breakpoint somewhere else in the code, it sometimes can stop at that breakpoint rather than stopping at the `__debugbreak()`.  And sometimes, when I run the code immediately when I get control of the debugger, it will sometimes result in a second break, as if it hit another `__debugbreak()`.  What's that all about?  Inconsistent debugging is certainly making this issue even harder to track down. >:(

Comment: DDE has in fact been outdated for many years since COM was introduced. Everything you're doing via DDE could instead be passed as command-line switches (e.g., `/p "%1"` or `"%1" /p`), and instead of listening for DDE your app can process the switches. Can't advise how long it would take to make the change, obviously, because I don't know anything about your codebase.

Comment: @KenWhite This is not possible when you have an MDI interface. The Shell Open and Print commands for MDI interfaces are always transmitted via DDE.

Comment: @xMRi: I'm  not sure that's true (there's a workaround), but this question doesn't say anything about MDI.

Comment: No. There is nothing about MDI, but I know the registry entries for MDI. And they seem identical  here. The workaround is just the the SDI settings in the registry!

Comment: This is indeed a MDI app.

Answer (score 0):

1. This DDE stuff is still the in use for MDI interfaces. So if one EXE opens different files.
2. If you can launch you application multiple times and this is OK, for the customer, switching the entries in the registry to the normal place holders from the SDI is OK too.
3. Usually this message is shown from the explorer, if the EXE doesn't get ready in a specific time to accept the DDE commands.

So the main question for you is: What is changed or so slow in the application that the DDE messages are not retrieved.

On case would be if it takes a real long time until the message loop starts. A running message loop for the main window is required for DDE support.

SetWindowPos istself will not be the problem, but it might cause hundreds of messages (WM_SIZE, ...) to be fired to your application, and every handler in your application here might be the problem.

Just place a little timer inside the application in front of the SetWindowPos and check how long it takes to return...

Check how long the app takes, until InitInstance is exited with TRUE. After InitInstance exits CWinApp::Run starts and the message loop starts.

Comment: I'll look up the timings, but just to let you know, if I put a breakpoint right in front of the `::SetWindowPlacement()` call using a `__debugbreak()` intrinsic and just step over that call any time before Explorer would time out, the error message will immediately pop up.  So, I don't think latency is the issue here.  Also, there is a lot of message processing that happens before this as it is creating the MDI window.

Comment: Then the reason is, that something inside your complete structure launches a window that accepts the DDE messages AND a message loop starts! This window doesn't understand and react on the DDE stuff and you get the error...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inside your complete structure launches a window".  I've also found that if I delay execution of the application by making the debugger pop up when the executable is launched, it will actually bring up the document, albeit after a bit of a delay.

Comment: I want to say: Something in your code structure, opens a window that accepts window messages...

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem.

My solution was to add the ../ddeexec/* section in the registry on application startup and then remove them on application exit.

Not a very nice solution but it is easy to do, and it works.